# How to ignore files/directories in "git archive" and only create an archive of a subdirectory?

Tags: git, gitattributes, git-archive

**TL;DR:** The `git archive` command seems to only either archive a single subdirectory *or* adhere to `.gitattributes` and exclude files/directories from the resulting ZIP, but cannot do both.

Say I have this directory structure in my git archive (simplified for reasability):

```
.
├── assets
├── build
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── CONTRIBUTORS
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── scripts
├── src
│   ├── background
│   ├── common
│   ├── icons
│   ├── _locales
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── options
│   ├── popup
│   └── tests
└── tests -> src/tests
```

Now I want to get **an ZIP (or tar) archive** with the following content:

- content of `src` directory only, as this is the source code I want to archive. Without the `src` directly, itself, however.
- inside of these directories I may want to ignore more folders and files. E.g. `tests` needs to be ignored, obviously.

So in the end, the archive should e.g. look like that:

```
.
├── background
├── common
├── icons
├── _locales
├── manifest.json
├── options
└── popup
```

Now, I thought `git archive` is a great tool for that. You can [archive a subdirectory only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350939/git-archive-a-subdirectory) and use [`.gitattributes` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464258/how-do-i-use-gitattributes-to-avoid-including-a-folder-in-git-root-but-include) with `export-ignore` to exclude directories and files wherever I want.

The aim is to also use `.gitattributes` recursively inside multiple subfolders, so I can also always exclude single files from the archive without knowing the upper folder structure. (That's useful for included libraries e.g.)

I also noticed you [may need to add the parameter `--worktree-attributes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5624398/5008962) so git picks up the `.gitattributes` files everywhere, where it finds it. And I have use `**` to exclude subdirectories. That's fine.

So (for testing here) I tried this:

```
$ git archive --worktree-attributes --format=tar HEAD:src | tar t
```

So only archiving the subdirectory works without any problems, but excludes files did not work.

E.g. I put this `.gitattributes` into the `src` directory:

```
tests export-ignore
tests/** export-ignore
```

Now, running the command mentioned above, it still includes the `tests` dir content.
However, if I run `git archive --worktree-attributes --format=tar HEAD | tar t`, i.e. not archive the subdirectory, the list ends with:

```
src/popup/[…]
tests
```

This means it excludes the content of the `tests` dir. For some reason, it did not exclude the dir itself, but that may be another issue on my side.

In contrast, if I put the follwing file into the root directory, the whole `src/tests` dir is excluded (although I had said they semantically mean the same):

```
src/tests export-ignore
src/tests/** export-ignore
```

My git version: 2.17.2
Fedora 28

**Edit:** I noticed now it somehow seems to work when I put the `.gitattributes` file into the *root dir*, but mention the file paths relative to the `src` dir. I.e. doing this (also tested with file exclusion):

```
tests export-ignore
tests/** export-ignore
manifest.json export-ignore
```

…somehow makes it work with the `src` archive command. Now, it does not work with archiving the whole dir anymore (but that is okay).
However, if I put this file anywhere else (like in the `src` dir) it again does not work…

And as my aim is to have `.gitattributes` files in subdirectories to exclude specific stuff in these directories, this still does not work as expected.

Comment: check out [gitzip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitzip) 
you can use exclude option as
`gitzip -s src/ -d your.zip -x test`